# Two views have the same layout path, but server error on one of them and not the other. "Layout page could not be found at the following path."

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In my ASP.NET MVC application I'm getting a server error (HttpException) when it tries to find the layout I've specified. I specify the **same** filepath for the layout in two views, but it works in one of them and not in the other.

Here is the code at the top of `Admin/Index.cshtml`:

```
@model IEnumerable<MultipleUserTesting.Data.User>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Admin: All Users";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

and here is the code at the top of `Admin/Edit.cshtml`:

```
@model MultipleUserTesting.Data.User 

@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Admin: Edit User: " + @Model.Name; 
    Layout = "∼/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; 
    }
```

Here is the error message, which occurs on the Edit page but *not* on the Index page:

> The layout page "∼/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml" could not be found at the following path: "~/Views/Admin/∼/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml".

I don't understand why it's trying to append the specified path onto `Views/Admin`, and I am confused because `Admin/Index.cshtml` specifies the same path and it works fine there.

Here is my directory structure:

[image: file-directory-structure]

As you can see, both files are in the same folder. Is `Admin/Index` "special" in some way because it's an `Index` page?

Hope this is enough information. I can post the stack trace if need be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try by removing the tild sign

```
Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
```

It is not very clear why using tild sign gives issue. starting with forward slash "/" will work as it consider the path from root of the application.

Comment: Tilda means root directory